# Open Office CMS?

Tags: sharepoint, content-management-system, openoffice.org

Is there a CMS which integrates into Open Office similarly to Share point/MS Office?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Alfresco](http://www.alfresco.com/) has a [plugin](http://forge.alfresco.com/frs/?group_id=157&release_id=295) for Open Office. It is not supported by either team, but it has the in-application integration that you see with SharePoint.

Answer (score 0):

I heard there was also a more official Alfresco integration to come out of Sun - not sure what's the status of that.  Alfresco also has recently implemented the SharePoint protocol, allowing to use MS Office with Alfresco as the backend without having to install any plugins (i.e. MS Word thinks it's talking to SharePoint)